# Why cast null into variables in cleanup code?

Tags: c#, .net, dispose, resource-cleanup

When viewing code from certain libraries in C# (using decompiling by Resharper), I sometimes come across cleanup code that looks like this:

```
public class Something
{
    private SomeObject _someObject;

    ...

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _someObject = (SomeObject) null;
    }
}
```

What is the benefit of casting `null` to the type of the field that is being cleared here?

Comment: That's just the decompiler failing to represent the *actual* source code that generated the IL it's trying to compile.  The cast does nothing in that code.  You should always be somewhat wary of decompiled code.

Comment: @Servy I suspected as much, but now I know for sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A decompiler cannot distinguish between assigning `null` without a cast and with a cast, since they do the same thing and compile to the same IL. Since `null` sometimes does need to be cast, e.g. when calling an overloaded method, some decompilers may always include the cast for simplicity.

There is no benefit here and I strongly suspect the original code did not include the cast.